# Error while trying to install modules via pip2 in a homebrew-based python 2.7 installation

Tags: homebrew, python

I have installed python 2.7 using Homebrew on a Mac OSX 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

```
$ which python2
/usr/local/bin/python2

$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python2
/usr/local/bin/python2 -> ../Cellar/python/2.7.14/bin/python2
```

When trying to install modules with pip2 (such as matplotlib) I get an error message such as:

```
$ pip2 install matplotlib
```

[...]

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/massimopinto/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/six.py'
```

inspecting the file to which access is apparently denied reveals that the file should be accessible with read+write permissions. 
If that adds any element, running a sample python script that imports the matplotlib module returns that matplotlib is not installed, while I can see one such module under:

```
~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/
```

I have probably messed up a previous python 2.7 installation with the installation that I have made using Homebrew. How do I tell python2 that a matplotlib module exist or, better perhaps, get pip2 to function?

Comment: Do you have write access to `~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`?

Comment: @patrix no, it belonged to root. I had probably `sudo` installed python via bundle earlier on. Changing ownership with `chown` brought things back to normal. Thank you. Now _matplotlib_ is indeed installed in `~/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages but python2.7` won't find it when loading the module. That goes off topic here though.